# Know of an OCaml IDE?

Tags: linux, ide, ocaml, typerex

Know of an OCAML/CAML IDE?  Especially one that runs on Linux?

Comment: You can try [Cameleon](http://home.gna.org/cameleon/).

Comment: Have a look at <a href="http://www.geany.org/">Geany</a>.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Emacs in [Caml mode](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~scott/pl/caml/emacs.html), or [Tuareg mode](https://who.rocq.inria.fr/Albert.Cohen/tuareg/index.html.en), or [TypeRex mode](http://www.typerex.org/).  TypeRex adds auto-completion to Taureg in emacs - a really nice feature for people who prefer the more graphical IDE's.

Comment: I use Emacs with Tuareg mode; most OCaml hackers use Emacs its seems.  There do, however, exist other IDE's as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: @Pi. how can i download TypeRex on Ubuntu 12.04. I am new to Linux could you help ? Do i have to disable Tuareg mode when i install Type Rex, and how ?

Comment: a nice alternative to TypeRex for auto-completion is merlin: https://github.com/def-lkb/merlin

Answer (score 15):

There is [Camelia](http://camelia.sourceforge.net/). You can also [integrate OCaml into Eclipse](http://mirror.ocamlcore.org/wiki.cocan.org/ocaml_and_eclipse.html). Also in Emacs you can use ocaml-mode and tuareg-mode.

Answer (score 11):

I vote [OcaIDE](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/). Now it has upgraded to v1.2.5. it become an up-to-date IDE (supporting ocaml 3.10-3.11, especially ocamlbuild, which is a great time-saver) and armed with rich, stable features.

I've installed OcaIDE on an eclipse 3.5(Galileo) and it works well.

Comment: Works well enough for me, too. The correct link is http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/ though.

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 modes for Emacs for working with OCaml: ocaml-mode and [tuareg-mode](http://www-rocq.inria.fr/~acohen/tuareg/).  Both are available via apt, or on the web.

They provide syntax-highlighting and tuareg-mode includes interfacing to the OCaml top-level and debugger.

Answer (score 6):

There are also a few `vim` files you can [load](http://www.ocaml.info/vim/) [up](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1197)... Take a look at the list of tools on the [`hump`](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?sort=-1&browse=12) and [`godi`](http://www.camlcity.org/), for extra tools. And be sure to compile with `-dtypes` on so you can take advantage of the annotation files to determine the types with a keystroke.

You can also use netbeans as an ide with an [ocaml plugin](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.cgi?contrib=705).

Answer (score 4):

It's actually possible to use OCaml via DrScheme if that's your thing.

http://coach.cs.uchicago.edu:8080/display.ss?package=drocaml.plt&owner=abromfie

Just run '(require (planet abromfie/drocaml:2:0/tool))' in DrScheme and you'll then be able to select the OCaml language.

Answer (score 4):

You can try NetBeans based [OcamlIDE](http://ocamlplugin.loki-a.com).

Answer (score 2):

http://ocaml.eclipse.ortsa.com:8480/ocaide/

I just found an eclipse plugin for it which may be promising.  Doesn't look too active.  I'll try it and report back on results.

ewwwe....emacs?  anything in vi?  ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  I've foudn that the plugin seems to work ok with Eclipse 3.4.  It isn't very pretty, but it seems to be functional.  I haven't tried the debugger yet, but when I do, I'll add another comment on my impressions.

Answer (score 2):

See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582388/looking-for-ocaml-ide/9414666#9414666) for [**TypeRex**](http://www.typerex.org/), a development environment for OCaml.

Answer (score 1):

Check out eclipse plugin for OCaml if you prefer to work on eclipse platform. 
For example, like this one:  http://ocamldt.free.fr/

Other than that, starting directly from plain editors like emacs or vim is good enough for programming. Besides, it can help you to learn better about the syntax of the language and the compiling process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit, compile and run simple Ocaml codes even online with [ideone](http://ideone.com/YNQhz).
There are also apps for mobile devices, which allows you to program/experiment with your smartphone.