# Compiling ocaml in notepad++

Tags: ocaml, notepad++

I'm learning OCaml at the moment and was wondering if it is possible to let Notepad++ take care of interpreting my scripts and display the output in the compiler window?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is not what you're looking for... but the emacs mode for o'caml is really good. The other ides not so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad++, atleast the version I have, doesn't have an OCaml mode.

Have a look at this link for a list of OCaml IDEs:
[Know of an OCAML IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118935/know-of-an-ocaml-ide)

Comment: Can we do it like Scite does Ruby? Just pointing to the ocaml compiler and viewing the output in compiler window?

Comment: I'm not an expert but as far as I know the best you can comeup with is a batch file that you can execute that calls the ocaml compiler.

But then you have to fiddle with the name and dependencies and by that point you really are better off with a true ide or having a command line open to call out to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

> chollida
>
> > But then you have to fiddle with the
> >     name and dependencies and by that
> >     point you really are better off with a
> >     true ide or having a command line open
> >     to call out to the compiler.

I don't have experience with notepad++, but it sounds like [ocamlbuild](http://brion.inria.fr/gallium/index.php/Ocamlbuild) will help in the compilation process.