# IDE for OCaml language

Tags: ide, ocaml

Is there any trusted OCaml IDE other than Camelia ?

I would prefer an eclipse based IDE if existed.

Comment: Lot of useful content: https://github.com/rizo/awesome-ocaml

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Edit: a decade later (2022), [VS Code OCaml Platform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ocamllabs.ocaml-platform) is probably the best option.

Editors

• Emacs

◦ ocaml-mode from the standard distribution

◦ alternative tuareg-mode https://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/tuareg/

− cheat-sheet: [http://www.ocamlpro.com/ﬁles/tuareg-mode.pdf](http://www.ocamlpro.com/%EF%AC%81les/tuareg-mode.pdf)

◦ camldebug intergration with debugger

◦ type feedback with C-c C-t key shortcut, needs .annot ﬁles

• Vim

◦ OMLet plugin
[http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~dbaelde/productions/omlet.html](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/%7Edbaelde/productions/omlet.html)

◦ For type lookup: either https://github.com/avsm/ocaml-annot

− or http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2025

− also? http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1197

• Neovim

◦ Install ocaml-lsp-server in opam, add lspconfig in neovim and enable ocamllsp in lspconfig

• Eclipse

◦ OCaml Development Tools http://ocamldt.free.fr/

◦ an old plugin OcaIDE http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/

• TypeRex http://www.typerex.org/

◦ currently mostly as typerex-mode for Emacs but integration with
other editors will become better

◦ Auto-completion of identiﬁers (experimental)

◦ Browsing of identiﬁers: show type and comment, go to deﬁnition

◦ local and whole-program refactoring: renaming identiﬁers and compilation units, open elimination

• Some dedicated editors

◦ OCamlEditor http://ocamleditor.forge.ocamlcore.org/

◦ ocamlbrowser inspects libraries and programs

− browsing contents of modules

− search by name and by type

− basic editing, with syntax highlighting

◦ Cameleon http://home.gna.org/cameleon/ (older)

◦ Camelia http://camelia.sourceforge.net/ (even older)

NEW: editor [OCaml-top](http://www.typerex.org/ocaml-top.html), with syntax highlighting, indentation, type display, work well on all systems.

NEW: [Merlin](https://github.com/def-lkb/merlin), similar to TypeRex but works better with work-in-progress files, has front-ends to Vim and Emacs currently.

Answer (score 12):

**VSCode with ReasonML / OCaml plugin:**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

*Install the VSCode plugin/extension with:*

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**Jetbrains / IntellijIDEA ultimate:**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

*With Jetbrains, install the plugin here:*

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You get intelli-sense / auto-complete with both editors using these plugins.

Comment: I like Jetbrains products, so I pay about $150/year for IDEA Ultimate which includes all Jetbrains language plugins tmk.

Comment: I've used both VSCode and Jetbrains. VSCode's color coding seem light years away and I've gone ahead with using VSCode

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can check this topic: [Looking for OCaml IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582388/looking-for-ocaml-ide/9414666#comment20622124_9414666)

For eclipse based IDE you have [OcaIDE](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/)